# Jira jql search not working with special character '-' or '&'

Tags: jira, jql

I couldn't get jql to work properly in jira (my version: v.7.6.5)

Say if I have a field named `location` and here's the value for the location field:
`Seattle - East`

And when I search in jql with query:
`location ~ "Seattle - East"` nothing would come back.

Can anyone help with searching string with special characters such as `-` or `&`?

ps. I've read documents from Atlassian to escape characters with `\` and `\\` it doesn't seem to work well with `&`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're searching a custom text field named Location based on the operator.

The search `location ~ "Seattle - East"` is searching for values that contain Seattle and do not contain East.

To search for an exact phrase you confusingly need to have a nested set of double quotes: `location ~ "\"Seattle - East\""`

I'm pretty sure that even in that scenario Jira will just ignore the -

Note that if you want more reliable reporting out of a custom field, a select list might be a better fit for a fixed number of location options. Then you could do a search like `location = "Seattle - East"`

Comment: thank you i was looking for 2 days for this

Answer (score -1):

As per the Atlassian documentation for Special characters, only space (' ') is listed but not both **`-`** or **`&`**.
The remedy as suggested by Atlassian JIRA is perfectly apt, escaping the space in the advised location (Seattle - East) should resolve the issue.

**NOTE**: When I'm trying to create labels or Projects with spaces, it doesn't even allow me to create one.
Creating a label called `Super Man` creates two labels `Super`,`Man`

Hope this helps.